# Como alinear un texto en flutter para hacer el menu de un local

Tags: flutter

Estoy desarrollando una app en Flutter para un menu en el cual quiero tener un resultado como el siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que he estado probando es el siguiente, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado.

```
return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text( text, style: style, )),
              const SizedBox( width: 15 ),
              Text( '\$ $price', style: style,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Divider( color: Colors.white.withOpacity( 0.5 ),),
      ],
    );
```

y el resultado que tengo es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el problema lo resolvi con el siguiente código con la ayuda de otros usuarios de Stackverflow en Ingles.

```
return SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded( child: Text( text, style: style, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ) ),
          ],),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text( 
                '.' * 150, 
                style: style, 
                maxLines: 1, 
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,)),
            SizedBox(
              width: 80,
              child: Text( 
                '\$ $price', 
                style: style,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,)),
          ],
        ),
        
      // Divider( color: Colors.white.withOpacity( 0.5 ),),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Este fue el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo podrías hacer directamente con un `Row` en lugar de usar el `ListTile`, te quedaría algo así:

```dart
return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                           child: Text(
                            text,
                            style: style,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                                  height: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '\$ $price',
                            style: style,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```

Comment: Ya habia probado algo parecido y funciona bien mientras el texto del menú no exceda de la primera línea, porque si el menú y el precio exceden el espacio disponible para una línea provoca un desvordamiento. Gracias de todas formas y Saludos.

Comment: solo necesitas definir el tamaño máximo para el texto y hacerlo multilinea, es sencillo, actualizaré mi respuesta

Comment: le agregué un Expanded al Text y ya